# Sum of $a^{*n}b^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How can I calculate a finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{*k}b^k$, where $a^{*k} = a^{a^{…^{a^a}}}$, $a$ written $k$ times?

P.S. a is greater then zero, otherwise we have to deal with complex numbers

Comment: Do you wish you to have the value for specific values of $a,b,n$?

Comment: @Math-fun I am looking for a general formula for any a>0, arbitrary b and n

Comment: Why do you expect a "general" formula? You already have a formula. It might not be possible to have a "nicer" one.

Comment: Here $a^*k}$ is tetration. Don't expect too much.

Comment: @Wuestenfux do u know anything about it that could maybe help? I am out of ideas

Comment: Computation of tetration is intractable.